# Pulse counter in verilog

Tags: verilog, hdl, vlsi

I am trying to build a pulse which is goes high for 8 pulses of clock and goes low for rest. So when enable and clock is high pulse goes high while after 8 pulses of clock pulse goes low. How can i implement and approach this in verilog. Here's what I have done till so far.

```
module clkgenerator(
  input clk,
  input [3:0] count = 4'b0,
  input enable,
  output andpulse
   );
  always@(posedge enable and posedge clk)
  begin
    andpulse <= 1;
      if(count == 4'b1000);
        andpulse <= 0;
        count <= 4'b0;
      else
        count <= count + 1;
      end 
  endmodule
```

But this throws and error

> Error: C:\altera\14.0\clkgenerator.v(3): near "=": syntax error,
>   unexpected '=', expecting ')'

Need help.

Comment: it is a correct message, you cannot initialize module ports.

Answer (score 1):

**This code generates HIGH output for 8 clock cycles as it detects positive edge of `enable` (as it seems to be what the problem asks).**

As it is clear from your problem description, logic, and attempt, you do not need `count` as an input (you cannot initialize your input, because they are triggered from outside of the module). And as @Mortada stated, you should not put `enable` in the sensitivity list of the always block and it is better to detect positive edge of `enable` signal inside always block. Positive edge of `enable` means => previous value of `enable` was 0 and now it is 1. In addition, you should use an initial block to initialize your registers.So the following code should be fine:

```
module clkgenerator(
   input clk,
   input enable,
   output reg andpulse
); 

reg [3:0] count;
reg previous_enable; //stores previous value of enable (1 clock earlier) 
reg pulse_enable; //enables the pulse if positive edge of enable is detected
initial // this block is used to initialize the registers
begin
  count <= 4'b0000;
  andpulse <= 1'b0;
  pulse_enable <= 1'b0;
  previous_enable <= 1'b0;
end
always@(posedge clk)
begin
if(enable > previous_enable) //if enable > previous_enable it means positive edge was detected
     pulse_enable <= 1'b1; //makes if condition that generates the pulse True for 8 clock cycles
if(pulse_enable)
begin
  andpulse <= 1;
  if(count == 4'b1000)
  begin
    andpulse <= 0;
    count <= 4'b0;
    pulse_enable <= 1'b0;
  end
  else
    count <= count + 1;
end
else
  count <= 1'b0;

previous_enable <= enable; //to be used in next stage
end //end of always block
endmodule

//This code is error free
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
change

```
   module clkgenerator(
  input clk,
  input [3:0] count = 4'b0,
  input enable,
  output andpulse
   );
```

to:

```
module clkgenerator(clk,count, enable, andpulse);
input clk, enable;
input [3:0] count = 4'b0000;
output andpulse;
```

Not sure if this will work.

Comment: No, that won't work. You can't initialize an `input` using the old port syntax either.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to declare count and andpulse as registers:

   ```
   module clkgenerator(
      input clk,
      input reg [3:0] count = 4'b0,
      input enable,
      output reg andpulse
   );
   ```
2. You shouldn't put enable in the sensitivity list of the always block. Put it instead in an if condition:

   ```
   always@(posedge clk)
   if(enable)
   begin
     andpulse <= 1;
     if(count == 4'b1000)
     begin
       andpulse <= 0;
       count <= 4'b0;
     end
     else
       count <= count + 1;
     end
   endmodule
   ```

Comment: Your first point gives an error "Port mode is incompatible with declaration: count". Don't know what does this mean.

Comment: Verilog does not support default values for inputs. `input [3:0] count = 4'b0,` needs to be change to to `input [3:0] count,`. Inputs cannot be assigned either.